# How do you pipe to an object in another require module

Tags: famo.us

I have a scrollview in a module which loads views which are returned from other modules.

**Module containing scrollview:**

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var View = require('famous/core/View');
    var Utility = require('famous/utilities/Utility');
    var Scrollview = require('famous/views/Scrollview');
    var HomeView = require('views/HomeView');
    var DescriptionView = require('views/DescriptionView');

    var paginationView = new Scrollview({
        direction: Utility.Direction.X
    });

    var AppViews = [
        HomeView,
        DescriptionView
    ];

    paginationView.sequenceFrom(AppViews);

    module.exports = paginationView;
});
```

**Here's the module code**

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var View = require('famous/core/View');
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var FlexScrollView = require('famous-flex/FlexScrollView');
    var MainView = require('views/MainView');
    var EventHandler = require('famous/core/EventHandler');

    function HomeView() {
        View.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    HomeView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
    HomeView.prototype.constructor = HomeView;

    HomeView.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {};

    var homeView = new HomeView();
    var scrollView = new FlexScrollView();

    homeView.add(scrollView);

    for (var i = 0, temp; i < 40; i++) {
        var surface = new Surface({
            content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
            size: [undefined, 200],
            properties: {
                backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
                lineHeight: "200px",
                textAlign: "center"
            }
        });

        surface.pipe(scrollView);
        // ... I want to pipe to the parent scrollview here ...
```

How could I pipe the surfaces from the second module to the scrollview in the first module? I'm still learning the whole event piping and am not sure how I would implement it here. I know that since I'm inheriting from the famous View module I should be able to access some advanced event management, but am  in the dark as to how I'd do it in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module `HomeView` extends the Famo.us `View`, so you can pipe the surfaces to the event handlers in `HomeView`

```js
// ... I want to pipe to the parent scrollview here ...
Surface.pipe(this._eventOutput);
```